# Grouping Data on Columns in Ireport- Jasper Report Designer

Tags: jasper-reports

Need a report like this in ireport

#### column1  |  column2 |   column3

x                 | a                                 |  a1
                          
                                                             |     a2

---

| b                 |  b1 
                                     | b2

---

| c                  | c1 
                                     | c2

Comment: Maybe I'm not getting the point corrctly but why don't you try to uncheck "print repeated values" while using groups?

Answer (score 0):

In the Report Inspector, right-click on the report name and click Add Report Group. Add a group for the field that defines column1, then add a group for column2, and finally a group for column3. In your query, be sure to order by column1, column2, column3. See page 113 (Chapter 7, Bands and Groups) of the iReport Ultimate Guide linked below.

Reference: [iReport Ultimate Guide](http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/ireport-ultimate-guide)